# scroll within div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have one `<div>` with `overflow:auto`. This `<div>` contains a `<form>` with a Search bar.
I am displaying the records fetched, in the same form, now all I need is to scroll the `<div>`  (where my search results start displaying) to the top of its container `<div>` (and not to the top of the page).

check the jsfiddle created.
http://jsfiddle.net/tusharjs/wGUE2/15/

Here, I have tried a solution I found on stackoverflow, but it scrolls the desired `<div id="scrollto">` to top of page and not to the top of the `<div id="maincontent">`.

Thanks

Comment: check the fiddle, when you inspect the element `<div id="scrollto">` you will find that, it is scrolled to top. I want its top to start from the `<div id="maincontent">`.

Clear?

Comment: I'm very sorry that I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `.offset()` method to get the element's actual top and subtract that from the amount to scroll.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  var elem = $('#scrollto');
  if(elem)
  {
    var main = $("#maincontent"),
        t = main.offset().top;
        main.scrollTop(elem.offset().top - t);
  }
});
```

[Here's my fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/s93jryL7/5/)

It might be more impressive to animate the scroll:

```
main.animate({scrollTop: elem.offset().top - t}, 500);
```

The second parameter above is the duration in milliseconds. The updated example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/482mK/58/).

Comment: Austin Mullins - your .animate() call above uses elem.offset().top but in your jsfiddle example the .animate() call uses elem.position.top()

Comment: @paparush Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the fiddle to match the answer. While playing with it, it looks like position() and offset() just happened to be returning the same values because there was nothing else on the page.